# Implementation of toString method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reference, tostring, primitive-types

When I want to print an empty array of the `Boolean` (reference type), the result is as ***output #1***. But when I want to print a primitive boolean type empty array, ***output #2*** is the result. I know that the `toString()` method in the `Object` class is running by default. The default implementation of this method is as follows:

```
this.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());
```

But it is interesting **why** **Z** is written in the output of primitive type however for int is **I**?

```
public class ToStringApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Boolean[] refs = new Boolean[1];
    System.out.println(refs);         
    // output #1: [Ljava.lang.Boolean;@3764951d

    boolean[] prims = new boolean[1];
    System.out.println(prims);        
    // output #2: [Z@4b1210ee

    int[] ints = new int[0];
    System.out.println(ints);
    // output #3: [I@4d7e1886

  }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Why Z is written in the output of boolean (primitive type) array however for int type is I?

Comment: Because `[Z` is the name of `boolean[].class`, and `[I` is the name of `int[].class`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the Javadoc of `Class`'s `getName()` says:

> **String java.lang.Class.getName()**
>
> Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array
> class,primitive type, or void) represented by this Class object,as a
> String.
> ...
> If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the
> internal form of the name consists of the name of the element type
> preceded by one or more '[' characters representing the depth of the
> array nesting. The encoding of element type names is as follows:
>
> | **Element Type** | **Encoding** |
> | --- | --- |
> | **boolean** | **Z** |
> | byte | B |
> | char | C |
> | class or interface | Lclassname; |
> | double | D |
> | float | F |
> | **int** | **I** |
> | long | J |
> | short | S |

As you can see, `B` is already taken by `byte`, so `boolean` required a different letter.